# Remove empty line from string C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

How can I remove empty line from a string for example:

Turn this:

[image]

to This:

[image]

I used this code `text.Replace("\n","");` but it turns it to:

testtesttes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace two newline characters(if any). Following code will work on Unix as well as non unix platforms.

```
var stringWithoutEmptyLines = yourString.Replace(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    string data = stringData.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
```